# Azure DevOps Yaml Pipeline - Parameters in other projets

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

In a project I have a pipeline that runs based on parameters passed by the user when trying to run the pipeline manually, can I replicate this same pipeline for all my projects that use Yaml?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IwYV.png)
Example in image 'project name'

They are in the same organization but they are not in the same project and I don't want to have to copy all the yamls for each project is it possible?

I tried to create a Resource template based on the yaml that I have in another project but it gives me an error and when running it does not show the text box field